# Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install Hadoop-2.6.0 on ec2-instance.

I downloaded and installed Hadoop. i also set the environment variables. When trying to start the hdfs services I get following error.

[ec2-user@ip-10-177-1-69 sbin]$ ./start-dfs.sh
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
Error: Cannot find configuration directory: /home/ec2-user/hadoop2.6.0/etc/hadoop
Error: Cannot find configuration directory: /home/ec2-user/hadoop2.6.0/etc/hadoop
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
Error: Cannot find configuration directory: /home/ec2-user/hadoop2.6.0/etc/hadoop

Answer (score 0):

When you configure .bashrc change it to below, there was an error in the second line in the website. Source .bashrc after you're done making changes.

export HADOOP_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-2.6.0

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HOME/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop

export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-2.6.0

export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-2.6.0

export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-2.6.0

export YARN_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-2.6.0

## Set JAVA_HOME

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79.x86_64/jre

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

## Add Hadoop bin/ directory to PATH

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/hadoop-2.6.0/bin

Comment: check java -version  and use the same version in export JAVA_HOME